# To find / to look for / to detect

Tags: grammar, meaning

Whats the difference between 見つからない　and 見当たらない？

Is 見つけない　used for physical objects? Like I can’t find the book etc...

and 見当たらない eg -> I can't find that line on this page?

In the middle of all this where does 見出す fit in?

I want to know the difference in nuanaces please

Comment: You should probably change your question to be about 見つからない instead of 見つけない, since the former is intransitive like 見当たらない.

Answer (score 2):

見つけない　implies that something was lost and you are looking for it.

見当たらない means that you are looking for something and you cannot see it in your immediate vicinity (as the word implies, within your field of vision). I often use this phrase when looking for something on a piece of paper or a webpage.

Comment: `見つけない implies that something was lost and you are looking for it.` <-- That would be 見つ**から**ない.

Comment: @Chocolate 見つけない is active voice, みつからない is passive voice. The appropriate voice should be used.

Comment: You can say 見つからない when (i.e. 見つからない can imply that) something is lost and you're looking for it (close to 見つけられない), but not 見つけない in that situation (i.e. 見つけない can't imply that). 見つけない would be more like "won't (try to) find" (close to, but less natural than 探さない)

Comment: @Chocolate That's fair, but the question isn't what would be said but the difference between the two words presented.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, then how is 見出すdifferent from 見当たらない